# Inserting unicode characters into SQL but it throws an exception

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a response from c# into my database with a query that contains unique characters like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0A2k.png)
into my database column that is a nvarchar(max) but I keep getting this exception
" is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character. "

Tried to encrypt and decrypt but the decryption returned different characters.
Any idea how to insert it?

Comment: Please paste your text in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you just need a national character literal, i.e. `N'some unicode characters'`.

Comment: Please don't use links in your question, post all information as editable text in your question. Also please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: The problem seems to stem from you trying to pass binary data as (part of) a string. Don't do this. Create a `varbinary` column and pass the data from your C# code as a suitable *binary* parameter.

Comment: SQL Server works just fine with Unicode and needs absolutely no tricks. .NET strings are already Unicode. This means that *all* the C# examples you've seen are actually inserting Unicode strings. SO uses SQL Server and Unicode. Post your code as text in the question itself.

Comment: If you try to insert binary data into any text column, whether varchar or nvarchar, you'll get errors and actually lose any bytes that aren't valid text. The `�` character in Unicode text and `?` in ASCII text is used to replace invalid byte values. When that happens, those values are simply lost and can't be recovered

Comment: .zip files are not text files, they are binary files. Like Damien_The_Unbeliever said you need to be inserting this data into a `varbinary(max)` column. From the C# side you need to pass it in via an [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) from a `byte[]` object.